# Is this graph a Reuleaux triangle?

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

Given the following function:

$f(\theta) =
\begin{cases}
\cos(\theta) + \omega\sin(\theta),  & \text{if $0\le\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$} \\
\omega\cos(\theta-\frac{\pi}{2}) + \omega^2\sin(\theta-\frac{\pi}{2}),  & \text{if $\frac{\pi}{2}\le\theta<\pi$} \\
\omega^2\cos(\theta-\pi) + \sin(\theta-\pi),  & \text{if $\pi\le\theta<\frac{3\pi}{2}$}
\end{cases}$

where $\omega=-\frac{1}{2} + i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, is the graph of the function a Reuleaux triangle? If so, how does one prove it?

I tried graphing it and it sure looks like one:
[image: curved triangle]

**Edit:** A huge apology to everyone. The original function I wrote had a gigantic mistake because I misinterpreted the output of the program I wrote. I've already fixed it above. As you can see, the actual function I graphed has a weird domain of just $0\le\theta\lt3\pi/2$, which is probably why I got confused.

Either way, it turns out that dxiv's conclusion is still correct, so I accepted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close, but it is not a Reuleaux triangle. By direct calculation:

$$
\begin{align}
f(0) &= 1
\\ f(\pi/2) &= \frac{-1 + i \sqrt{3}}{2}
\\ f(3 \pi / 4) &= - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
\end{align}
$$

Then $\,\left|f(\pi/2) - f(0)\right|^2=3\,$ but $\,\left|f(3 \pi / 4) - f(0)\right|^2 \approx 2.91 \ne 3\,$ so the width is not constant.

---

[ *EDIT* ]   Updated to match the modification in the question.

Comment: Thanks for this. Apparently the function I originally described in my question was not what I had graphed (whoops), but even with my revised function you are still correct that the shape is not of constant width.